# Use regex to split string given a set of characters with exceptions

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I wish to use python's re module to split an expression

```
formula = '(ABC**2+3/(DEF[4:6]-2*GHI[-5:-2]))'
```

at all parentheses and mathematical operations (+,-,*,**,/).

However, I need to distinguish "-" characters that are math operations (subtraction) and others which are included in the square brackets that are considered part of the string.

So far, a working example looks like this:

```
import re

formula = '(ABC**2+3/(DEF[4:6]-2*GHI[-5:-2]))'

pattern = "[()+*/\-]"
split_expr = re.split(pattern, formula)

print(split_expr)
```

which yields

```
['', 'ABC', '', '2', '3', '', 'DEF[4:6]', '2', 'GHI[', '5:', '2]', '', '']
```

How do I need to adjust the regex pattern to achieve the desired output below where the string is not split if a "-" character is preceded by either  '[' or by ":"?

```
['', 'ABC', '', '2', '3', '', 'DEF[4:6]', '2', 'GHI[-5:-2]', '', '']
```

Also, I am not sure if there is a way to exclude the empty strings but this is not crucial.

Comment: I think you mean "preceded," not "followed".

Comment: Would `(?:\*\*|[()*+/]|(?<![[:])-)` work for you?  `\*\*` must precede `\*` in the alternation. [https://regex101.com/r/dj3ICF/1)

Comment: I don't know if there's any way to eliminate the empty strings at the beginning or end if the string begins and ends with punctuation.  You probably need to do that as a separate step.

Comment: Yes, I mean "preceded". Thanks for the heads up.  Updated the question.

Comment: Like this? https://ideone.com/NK8eh6

Comment: "where the string is not split if a "-" character is preceded by either '[' or by ":"?" - so you are looking for a *negative* (because you want to match when a certain character is *not* there) *lookbehind* (because you are checking for something *before* the character you want to match) *assertion* (because you don't want to treat the character as part of the match). Please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: I voted to reopen because I do not believe answers to the earlier question will help the OP answer his/her question, but I will ask: braunlee, would you have been able to answer your question had you only read the answers to the earlier question for which your question is claimed to be a duplicate (and not the comments and answers here)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I certainly would not have been able to produce an answer to my own question with the information from the other thread. I had been looking through the documentation and tutorials before but what I needed was a specific example with explanation. It's great to see all the different ways (here) to approach this problem. Thanks everybody!

Comment: You might find it easier just to match the variables and numbers: https://regex101.com/r/7ryrJ1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the not preceded by x operator (?<!x)

So a pattern like

plus or minus or * or ** or / or ( or )

`\+|-|\*{1,2}|/|\(|\)`

can become

plus or (not preceded by : or [) minus or * or ** or / or ( or )

`\+|(?<![:\[])-|\*{1,2}|/|\(|\)`

a nice way to write this in code could be

```
formula = '(ABC**2+3/(DEF[4:6]-2*GHI[-5:-2]))'
pattern = '|'.join(('\+', '(?<![:\[])-', '\*{1,2}', '/', '\(', '\)'))
# pattern = "\+|(?<![:\[])-|\*{1,2}|/|\(|\)"
split_expr = re.split(pattern, formula)

print(split_expr)
```

which outputs

`['', 'ABC', '2', '3', '', 'DEF[4:6]', '2', 'GHI[-5:-2]', '', '']`

additionally something like this might also be useful

```py
split_expr_with_operators = re.split('(' + pattern + ')', formula)
print(split_expr_with_operators)
```

which outputs both the operators and the other strings

`['', '(', 'ABC', '**', '2', '+', '3', '/', '', '(', 'DEF[4:6]', '-', '2', '*', 'GHI[-5:-2]', ')', '', ')', '']`

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work for you:

```
[()+*/]|\d-
```

It splits the string by all the characters in the group (`[]`) **or** by a "-" character following a digit (`\d`).
Alternatively, you can specify characters after which you do **not** want the "-" character to work as a separator (as you mentioned in your question):

```
[()+*/]|^[\[,:]-
```

For example

```
import re

formula = '(ABC**2+3/(DEF[4:6]-2*GHI[-5:-2]))'

pattern = "[()+*/]|^[\[,:]-"
split_expr = re.split(pattern, formula)
empty_removed = list(filter(None, split_expr))

print(split_expr)
print(empty_removed)
```

which will return

```
['', 'ABC', '', '2', '3', '', 'DEF[4:6]-2', 'GHI[-5:-2]', '', '']
['ABC', '2', '3', 'DEF[4:6]-2', 'GHI[-5:-2]']
```

Hope this helps! :)